# Microsoft.Graph.Beta.dll missing IPrintDocumentRequestBuilder.Content() despite MS Graph Explorer code snippets suggesting it?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, .net-core-3.1

[MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) shows C# code snippets of HTTP request you enter (which is a lovely feature).

The http request I entered is (I've replaced my GUIDs with {ID}):
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/print/printers/{printerID}/jobs/{jobID}/documents/{documentID}/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/print/printers/%7BprinterID%7D/jobs/%7BjobID%7D/documents/%7BdocumentID%7D/$value)

This is using the "Universal Print" API which is in Beta/Preview.

The code snippet MS Graph Explorer shows is:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var stream = await graphClient.Print.Printers["{printerID}"].Jobs["{jobID}"].Documents["{documentID}"].Content
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

However... When I pasted this code into my C# VS2019 .NET Core 3.1 code it complained that:

```
'IPrintDocumentRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no accessible extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'IPrintDocumentRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Which was a surprise, and worse the error seems to be right as when I look at Microsoft.Graph.Beta.dll (0.32.0-preview) via dotPeek there isn't a Content method for IPrintDocumentRequestBuilder.

Does anyone have any idea why the code snippet from MS Graph Explorer suggests a C# method that doesn't exist in the Microsoft.Graph.Beta.dll? Or better yet what I need to do to make it work?

My aim is to download the contents of a print job document via MS Graph Explorer.
X

Comment: Let me look into this..

Comment: What if you downgrade the above beta.dll to it last known working version?

Comment: @Dev have tried 0.31.0-preview and back to 0.28.0, no Content(). And then the error changes to "'PrintJob' does not contain a definition for 'Configuration'". Did find someone else has spotted this here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10655

Comment: Glad that you tried and able to track the related issue posted in Microsoft Github. Way to go!!

Comment: Haha! Good old GoogleFu. X

Comment: Moving this to answer. So it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

- As you faced the issue, you tried 0.31.0-preview and back to 0.28.0, no Content().
- Then the error changes to "'PrintJob' does not contain a
  definition for 'Configuration'".
- In the meanwhile, you did find someone else has spotted
  this [related thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10655).

Answer (score 0):

IPrintDocumentRequestBuilder.Content() is now present in the DLL.
The version that worked for me is the v0.38.0-preview https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/0.38.0-preview/